# How to allow camera permission popup while testing with cucumber-capybara(selenium -chromeDriver)

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, cypress, capybara

I have link that will open a new page to do some task. I can only proceed further only after allowing camera permissions.

**popup window**

[image: check here - Prompt- camera permission]

First a confirmation popup appears which ask for camera permissions. After clicking on allow button browser permission popup appears.
it's similar to all pops that appears when we visit any website

[image: check here - Browser permission popup]

I have a feature file written in Gherkin syntax and a step definition file written using capybara syntax.

**step definition**

```
Then('I click test link') do
  test_window = window_opened_by do
    find(:css, "a[href='example.com/test']").click()
    # sleep(5)
  end
  within_window test_window do
      click_button 'Allow'
  end
  sleep(10)
end
```

After clicking allow button browser permission pop appears.Please check the attached images.
**I need to allow that permission. can someone suggest how to do that using *capybara-cucumber with selenium chromeDriver*.**

If you have any idea how i can do the same thing in **cypress** please suggest. Cypress is not allowing camera permission. I have already used a npm module but it didn't worked for me.
Any other alternative to do the same ??

Comment: Re Cypress - was the npm module https://github.com/kamranayub/cypress-browser-permissions?

Comment: yes, i used that only.. when i checked for permission they were enabled but on browser it was showing camera access denied

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add the `--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream` or `--use-fake-device-for-media-stream` argument when you set the desired capabilities?